# Replace in a string different characters with other characters

Tags: javascript, replace

Suppose the string `One two (three)`

In PHP, in order to replace the spaces with a dash, and parentheses with an empty string, I'd do it like this: `str_replace( array( ' ', '(', ')' ), array( '-' ), $key )`, because `search` arg is an array, `replace` is an array also, and replace has fewer elements than search, so the remaining elements from search are replaced with an empty string...

I'm not very good in JS, so I needed to achieve something similar, like turning `One two (three)` to `One-two-three`, and tried with chained replace commands. But it doesn't work in the expected way. Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but what is it?

```js
var text="one two (three)";

alert(text.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(" ", "-"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace` will only replace the first occurence. Use `replaceAll` instead of `replace` to replace all occurrences.

```js
var text="one two (three)";

alert(text.replaceAll("(", "").replaceAll(")", "").replaceAll(" ", "-"));
```

Comment: That's indeed the solution. What's the problem with replace though? What am I missing?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace - "A string pattern will only be replaced once. To perform a global search and replace, use a regular expression with the g flag, or use replaceAll() instead."